# Solving $E$ from $j_i\cdot10^{((E-E_i)/b)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to solve $E$ from a relation
$$j_1\cdot10^{((E-E_1)/b_1)}=j_2\cdot10^{((E-E_2)/b_2}$$
My attempt was to take $\log_{10}$ from both sides, leading to
$$\log_{10}(j_1)+\frac{E-E_1}{b1}=\log_{10}(j_2)+\frac{E-E_2}{b_2}$$
$$\frac{E-E_1}{b_1}-\frac{E-E_2}{b_2}=\log_{10}(j_2)-\log_{10}(j_1)$$
$$E\cdot\left(\frac{E_2}{b_2}-\frac{E_1}{b_1}\right)=\log_{10}\left(\frac{j_2}{j_1}\right)$$
$$E=\log_{10}\left(\frac{j_2}{j_1}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{E_2}{b_2}-\frac{E_1}{b_1}\right)^{-1}$$

However, this is apparently wrong, since as this is a physical problem ([Tafel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafel_equation) for calculating corrosion potential) and $E$ should have units of volts, but now it is dimensionless, because also $b$ has units of volts. Also, when comparing the numerical solution between this and one given by Wolfram Alpha, the values are not the same.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{E-E_1}{b_1} - \frac{E-E_2}{b_2} =E\left(\frac{1}{b_1}-\frac{1}{b_2}\right)- \frac{E_1}{b_1}+\frac{E_2}{b_2} \neq E\left(\frac{E_2}{b_2} - \frac{E_1}{b_1}\right)$$

Comment: Oh, such a simple mistake! Thank you for pointing it out :)